# External Javascript function not called from onchange event of select

Tags: javascript

i have a javascript function in external file. This function is included via tag:

```
<script type="module" src="/js/geojson.js"></script>
```

The function should be called in onchange handler of  element:

```
<select id="name1" th:field="*{mapProjection2.name}" th:name="name"
                            class="form-control" onchange="loadData(geojsonGrid01, 
 geojsonProj01, geojsonCap01, ${'map02'},${'#grid2'},${'#coast2'},${'#cap2'});">
```

But instead i get the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

My js function looks like (functionality not relevant here):

```
import * as MapContainer from './leaflet/leaflet.js';

export function loadData(geojsonGrid, geojsonProj, geojsonCap, map, grid, coast, cap) {
...}
```

[image]

Comment: Your function is actually called, but you are missing an `)` somewhere thats causing it not to run properly

Comment: what are you trying to do with `${'map02'},${'#grid2'},${'#coast2'},${'#cap2'}` ? Getting elements? You should get elements with `$('#cap2')` for example.

Answer (score 1):

`${'map02'}` is invalid `JS` code, use `(` instead of `{`.

That could be the cause of your error, the syntax is not correct.

```
<select id="name1" th:field="*{mapProjection2.name}" th:name="name"
                            class="form-control" onchange="loadData(geojsonGrid01, 
 geojsonProj01, geojsonCap01, $('map02'), $('#grid2'), $('#coast2'),  $('#cap2'));">
```

Comment: This doesn't really fix enough, since `${'map02'}`  is not valid JS code.

Comment: True, but we dont know what he is trying to do, probably sending elements. Ill update my answer as soon as we know more.

Comment: With `geojsonGrid01` `geojsonProj01` and `geojsonCap01` i'm trying to transfer my JSON data structures. Indeed, it's an application for map visualisations...

Comment: Are those variables or just strings?

Comment: Those are Variables.

Comment: updated my answer, can you check if it worked?

Comment: It says: `Malformed markup: Attribute "+" appears more than once in element`

Comment: Updated my answer, in that case your only mistake was the `{` you used, those should be `(`

Comment: Now it says: `loadData is not defined at HTMLSelectElement.onchange`

Comment: @Jbadminton I have added a picture of developer console in my original post...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250028/discussion-between-luckymanstefan-and-jbadminton).